# How are mixed exponential distributions fitted?

Tags: distributions, mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution

A single exponential is defined as

$f(x;\beta)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\beta}e^{\frac{-x}{\beta}} & x \ge 0\\
0 & x<0
\end{cases}$

and the MLE of $\beta$ can be estimated from samples $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ using the $\hat{\beta}=\bar{x}$ according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution.

However in the mixed exponential case here:

$f(x;\beta)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\alpha}{\beta_1}e^{\frac{-x}{\beta_1}} 
+ \frac{(1-\alpha)}{\beta_2}e^{\frac{-x}{\beta_2}} & x \ge 0\\
0 & x<0
\end{cases}$

there are three parameters to estimate: $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$ and $\alpha$.
What is the standard way to estimate these parameters?

Comment: Have you tried writing down the likelihood function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can estimate via ML. A common method for this kind of optimization is to introduce unobserved random variables that indicates which mixture component an observation came from and to maximize the (expanded) objective function with an EM algorithm. The [mixtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/index.html) package in R has an implementation of this algorithm.